# Uitableview, json and detail tableview

Tags: mysql, ios, json, uitableview, nsarray

I am asking a very simple question for someone who has encountered this kind of problem, please don't mark it down because there are many approaches to a solution.

I have  a database which has cities and town, cities has many town, therefore, using one query displays many cities to correspond to the town. The result is as follows from mysql;
{City - town 1, town2, town 3} therefore if I want to display both the town and cities, I will end up with {city-town1, city-town2, city-town3}

I want to be able to compile all towns under a city, so that I can eventually use this source of array for my drilldown table, i.e on the first table; I want a list of non-repeating cities, on detail table, a list of all towns under that city. I only want to use one table and make the array dynamic such that I can add cities and towns without any problems (I have seen examples proposing different tables for different arrays)

I used this for- loop to iterate through mysql result

```
  for (int i=0; i<json.count; i++)
            {


           ids= [[json objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"Id"];
           cityName = [[json objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"cityName"];
           townName = [[json objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"townName"];
}
```

This gives me a list of cities but they are repeating;

I have been thinking about different approaches;
1)use @distinctunion- (Key-Value Coding) 
2)use two jsons (one for city and another for towns) -compile arrays under each then join them using common id
3)use an iteration, iterate as shown above, but also search for similar cityNames and group towns under cities

Has anyone encountered a similar situation? what did you do? could you  give an example if possible please

This is JSON Result for NSMutable Array of the above iteration

```
    2013-09-18 07:50:52.025 JSONDATA[7119:11603] (
    Bath,
    "Bath, Somerset"
)
2013-09-18 07:50:52.035 JSONDATA[7119:11603] (
    Bath,
    "Bath, Somerset"
)
2013-09-18 07:50:52.035 JSONDATA[7119:11603] (
    Bath,
    Keynsham
)
2013-09-18 07:50:52.035 JSONDATA[7119:11603] (
    Bath,
    Keynsham

)
```

Comment: The Question should be ease to understand . There may be a short story but not to be a chapter ..

Comment: Can you show the JSON output ..?

Comment: I have asked this question several time but i do not seem to get the correct answer, so I am hoping there is someone out there who has solved such a problem. I want to make it as clear as possible

Comment: Ok .. But very few of interested people to give the module level of suggestion ..So Can't you deal the expected output at Database itself . I mean, in Php or query level You should try to get the expected O/P  as JSON . Then it will be easy know .

Comment: Use nsdictionary, where the key is the city and the value is an array of towns.

Comment: @Kumar Ki,that sounds like the easiest way out, but can you accomplish that in one query? that is why I added number 3 suggestion that probably use two JSON, one for town and one for city. because distinct and group will only eliminate the repeating but not group the values of repeating. Can you give further suggestion please

Comment: @Calin Chitu, thanks I have that as option but what about a situation where you have shops under town i.e three level, four level hierarchy. Let's say we have cities, that have many towns and towns have many shops and shops have many shop owners. Could key-value option still work?

Comment: then the key will be the city, the value will be another nsdictionary, with key town and value shop, or another nsdictionary... and so on.